# Computing a potential with a complex integration

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to understand the link between $ \mathbb R^2 $ and $ \mathbb  C $.
I know how to compute potentials when I know the gradient of it :

$$ f(x,y) = \left( \frac {-x}{(x^2+y^2)^2 } , \frac {-y}{(x^2+y^2)^2 } \right) $$
gives 
$$ F(x,y) = \frac {1}{2(x^2+y^2) } $$

My question is,

> How can you find the same result with complex integration ?

---

My attempt :

using this formula  (and my calculator I admit)
$$\int  f(z) dz = \int u dx - v dy + i \int v dx + u dy $$

$$ \int \int  \frac {-x}{(x^2+y^2)^2 } +i \frac {-y}{(x^2+y^2)^2 }  dx dy 
= \frac { \arctan (\frac y x) } { 2x} - i \frac { 2y \ln(y) + \ln( \frac 1 { y^2 }) y - 2 \arctan (\frac x y ) x }  { 4 x y }$$

which looks like something not that afar from my result, but I'm not convinced.

So is it possible and how do you do this?

Comment: You should start by finding a complex function $f(z=x+i y)$ such that the first component of $f(x,y)$ is the real part and the second component is the imaginary part...

Comment: isn't it done ? Isn't what you're saying the last line in Latex?

Comment: Fabian was suggesting to express $f$ as a function of $z$, not $F$.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means @N74, Am I supposed to create artificially x + iy ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "artificially", but letting $z=x+iy$ can be a good substitution to find an expression for $f(z)$.

Comment: May you do a short and easy example? I still don't understand what would be a first ste to solve my problem.